# how to tell "dpkg" to NOT to download / install a broken source?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt, dpkg

Whenever I try to use apt-get/dpkg, it tries a to install a broken source. 
How can I tell it to NOT do so ?

here is its error:

```
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**UPDATE :**

I found the perfect solution here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/121226/how-to-completely-remove-a-oracle-jdk-that-didnt-install-properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define does this package depends on something and do you need it. If not just force to purge it with

```
aptitude purge oracle-java7-installer
```

or even

```
dpkg --force-all --purge oracle-java7-installer
```

If you need it try to determine why it is broken. Due to your posted error there is broken script in installer. So you'll need to fix it. The simplest way is to unpack it, fix script and repack. After that install should success.

Comment: Thanks ... It was an automatic installer problem. I installed and configured it manually, and it works fine ..

Comment: the problem still exists: 
`Download done.
sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u3-linux-x64.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
`

Answer (score 0):

you also need to install aptitude first as it is no longer default installed.
and use sudo privileges.

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

and

```
sudo aptitude purge oracle-java7-installer
```

or

```
sudo dpkg --force-all --purge oracle-java7-installer
```